# Proof that STCON is in NL

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs

What is the proof that STCON
(returns 1 if there is a path in the directed graph $G = (V,E)$ from $ s \in V$ to $t \in V$ and else, 0.

is indeed in NL? (Non-deterministic turing machines with logarithmic memory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an NL algorithm:

- Input: Graph, nodes $s,t$
- Count the number of nodes $n$
- Guess $\ell \in \{0,\ldots,n\}$
- Repeat $\ell$ times: Guess an out-neighbor $s'$ of $s$ and set $s \gets s'$
- Verify that $s = t$

Comment: Thanks. that's a great solution, I wonder how it can be implemented in $NC_2$ (boolean circuits with $POLY(V) $ size and $log^2 (V)$ depth)

Comment: Try using divide and conquer. It actually appears that directed reachability is in $\mathsf{AC}^1$, which is a potentially smaller class.